# Node.js starter, unknown error with testing

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js and I have a problem with testing which I can't figure out the problem, here is my error:

> gradeTests √ Can add new grade
> **× Can avarage grades**
>
> **AssertionError: NaN == 75**
> at Object.equal (C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\lib\types.js:83:39)
> at Object.exports.Can avarage grades (C:\Users\efi\Desktop\nodeFolder\tests\gradeTests.js:21:7)
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\lib\core.js:232:20
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:168:13
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:131:25
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:165:17
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:463:34
> at Object.exports.setUp (C:\Users\efi\Desktop\nodeFolder\tests\gradeTests.js:5:2)
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\lib\core.js:260:35
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:458:21
> at C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:163:13
> at iterate (C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:123:13)
> at async.forEachSeries (C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:139:9)
> at _asyncMap (C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:162:9)
> at Object.mapSeries (C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:152:23)
> at Object.async.series (C:\Users\efi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodeunit\deps\async.js:456:19)
>
> **FAILURES: 1/2 assertions failed (16ms)**

and here are my files:

```
var gradeBook = {

    _grades: [],
    addGrade: function(newGrade) {
       this._grades.push(newGrade); 
   },
   
   getCountOfGrades: function() {
        return this._grades.lenght; 
   },
   getAverage: function() {
       var total = 0;
       for(var i = 0; i < this._grades.lenght; i +=1 ) {
           total += this._grades[i];
       };
       return total / this._grades.lenght;
   },
   
   
   reset: function() {
       this._grades = [];
   }
   
};

exports.book = gradeBook;
```

and

```
var book = require("../lib/grades").book;

exports["setUp"] = function(callback) {
    book.reset();
    callback();
};

exports["Can add new grade"] = function(test) {
    book.addGrade(90);
    var count = book.getCountOfGrades();
    
    test.equal(count);
    test.done();
};

exports["Can avarage grades"] = function(test) {
    book.addGrade(100);
    book.addGrade(50);
    
    var average = book.getAverage();
    test.equal(average, 75);
    test.done();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typos in your code, `lenght` should be `length`.

Comment: Hoo mine, yes the problem has been fixed, dont know how I didnt noticed that, thank you.